# How to see if a credit card has been used before?

Tags: authorize.net

I'm trying to implement a referral system so each credit card can only be used once. Is it possible for Authorize.net so that I can use some kind of API and see if the current card has been used to pay on my site or not? Maybe something related to CIM?

Comment: How about logging which credit card was used before? You could use a mysql-database for example. I mean, if you are allowed to store those informations. If you are not, hash the Credit Card Informatios before saving them. This way nobody could access them and you could compare

Comment: @MathiasS. Storing card number is still pretty risky tho. And I've been using Authorize.net for years, lots of my customers have cc saved on authorize.net already. I don't think they will type in them again, since i've been using CIM, so they can just click pay instead of typing in the card # multiple times after once.

Comment: In this case, why dont you just call authorize.net and ask them for some way to do it? And then, if you have problems realizing the solution that they offered for you, you could come back again?

Comment: @MathiasS. They are closed now so I can't call until tmr. Just want to see if anyone knows the solution here.